# The variety $V_p$ given by $X^2 + Y^2 = pZ^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, self-learning

I'm doing exercise 1.10 in Silverman's Elliptic Curves. $p\ge 3$ is a prime. Part (a) asks for a proof that $p\equiv 1\mod{4}\iff V_p\cong \mathbb{P}^1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I proved this by (painfully) constructing an explicit bijection and inverse, using the fact that $x^2+y^2=p$ has a solution in rational numbers, by parametrizing solutions to the equation.

Part (b) asks for a proof that if $p, q\equiv 3\mod{4}$, $p\ne q$ then $V_p$ and $V_q$ are not isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$. I know that $V_p(\mathbb{Q}) = V_q(\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$, but I can't figure out how to use the fact that $p$ and $q$ are not expressible as a sum of two squares to show that no isomorphism exists. I constructed one proof that simply had to be wrong because it didn't use the congruence restrictions on $p$ and $q$. I'd appreciate a hint. *Please* don't post a complete solution; I want to figure this out myself.

**Note**: I interpret part (b) as asking: show that there is no isomorphism $\phi = [\phi_0,\phi_1,\phi_2]$ between
$$\{[a,b,c]\in\mathbb{P}^2(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})\,:\,a^2+b^2 = pc^2\}
\text{ and }
\{[d,e,f]\in\mathbb{P}^2(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})\,:\,d^2+e^2 = qf^2\}$$
where $\phi_i\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ (or, if you prefer, $\mathbb{Q}[V_p]$).

Comment: a bit stronger: if $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ is a (positive) prime, and $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q,$ then both $x,y \equiv 0 \pmod q.$ It follows that the ternary quadratic form $x^2 + y^2 - q z^2 \neq 0$ over the integers and rationals, unless $x=y=z=0.$ If there were a nontrivial integer solution, $x,y,z$ not all zero, there would be a solution with $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1.$ However, if $x^2 + y^2 - q z^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {q^2},$ all three of $x,y,z$ are divisible by $q.$ Contradiction. Might help.

Comment: Hint: I think the Chevalley-Warning theorem does it (this may be over-kill, but it's good to know, and it's  elementary).

Comment: @peterag I did see your comment; I too don't see yet how it can help, since $V_p$ and $V_q$ are defined over $\mathbb{R}$, not a finite field. I certainly agree that they cannot be isomorphic over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @rogerl You mean defined over the rationals, not reals, right? One can view the varieties as being defined over the integers  - certainly, in Silverman for instance, one does this all the time (models).  They reduce therefore to varieties over the finite field. If there is a rational isomorphism, it "should" extend to one over the integers, and therefore reduce to one over the finite field. One has to make sure that my "should" is correct, but I believe it is: remove any common $p$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @peterag If I understand Silverman's terminology properly (and I must say I find it pretty confusing), $V_p$ is a variety in $\mathbb{P}^2$, which according to the book means in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, so in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$. What the question asks is to prove that there is no isomorphism between $V_p$ and $V_q$ where the coefficients are all rational. If he really meant to say that $V_p(\mathbb{Q})$ and $V_q(\mathbb{Q})$ are not isomorphic, that is just false, since they are both $\emptyset$.

Comment: I should go take a look at the book. One can certainly view a variety as being 'defined' over a sub-field (here the rationals), if one can find equations for it with coefficients in that field. And you will see, in the book, for instance 'model', and 'minimal model' of an elliptic curve, where the coefficients are in a ring (the integers) for instance. However, my idea looks pretty bad, because of @GeorgesElencwajg's remark - and sadly, his kindly offered defense doesn't hold - I can't call myself a beginner, though possibly a doofus.

Comment: @peterag Agreed about definition over a subfield. But that is clearly not what is meant here, and in fact the definition of projective $n$-space over $K$ in the book is that it is denoted $\mathbb{P}^n$ or $\mathbb{P}^n(\bar{K})$ where $\bar{K}$ is an algebraic closure of $K$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Right, I assumed that from the problem statement, but surely it is true in that case that $V(k) \cong W(k)$ (over $k$)!

Comment: @rogerl Are you OK with the $p$-adics? Will's argument shows that $V_q( {\mathbb Q}_q) = \emptyset$.

Comment: I am. But remember that this exercise appears very early in Silverman, and I have no expectation that he envisioned a solution involving $p$-adics. But in any case, how does this observation solve the problem? Both $V_p(\mathbb{Q}_q)$ and $V_q(\mathbb{Q}_q)$ are empty.

Comment: I disagree: I think $V_p({\mathbb Q_q})$ is not empty. By Chevalley-Warning, there is a non-zero solution to the congruence on the form $\pmod q$. By Hensel's lemma, it lifts. (If this is wrong, I have a lot to delete today, don't I?)

Comment: The use of Hensel I have in mind is: write $f_p(x,y,z) = x^2 +y^2 - p z^2$.  There is a solution, with at least one of $x_0,y_0,z_0$ not divisible by $q$, say $z_0$. Fix $x_0, y_0$, and set $\tilde f_p(z) = f_p (x_0,y_0, z )$. Hensel's lemma applies, because $$\tilde f'_p(z_0) = -2 p z_0 \not \equiv 0 \pmod q,$$ so we obtain a solution with $z$ a unit in ${\mathbb Z}_q$. Therefore $V_p({\mathbb Q_q})\not=\emptyset$.  BTW, I grant your objection on using $p$-adics.

Comment: @peterag So here's where my knowledge of the subject is unclear: you have presented an argument that $V_p$ and $V_q$ are not isomorphic as varieties in $\mathbb{Q}_q$. Does that imply that they are not isomorphic as varieties in $\mathbb{C}$?  I don't see why it would.

Comment: The varieties $V_p$ and $V_q$ are isomorphic over $\mathbb C$, because they are then both isomorphic the projective lineover $\mathbb C$. This holds true over 'any' algebraically closed field $k$ - your 'painful' argument works, once there is a $k$-rational point. Now, I put 'any' in quotation marks, because there seem to be issues on reduction modulo $p$: my (erased) errors included (among other things)  not noticing that while the equation $x^2 + y^2 - pz^2=0$ (naively) reduces to $x^2 + y^2=0$, the latter is not absolutely irreducible - i.e. factors over $\overline {\mathbb  F}_p$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74298/discussion-between-rogerl-and-peter-a-g).

Comment: @rogerl - later on, ok?

Comment: Sure. I'm at least glad that I didn't ask a question whose answer was trivial.

Comment: @rogerl - see the further comments (after your one which started "funny you should say...") under GE's answer...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that the conics $x^2+y^2-pz^2$ are not isomorphic over $\mathbb Z$ for different $p$'s.
For every prime $p$ we  have a well defined reduction map $$r_p:\mathbb P^2=\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb Z}\to \mathbb P^2_{\mathbb F_p}$$ which in particular on rational points $A=[a:b:c]\in \mathbb P^2(\mathbb Q)$ (where $a,b,c$ are integers without any common prime factor) is given by  $r_p(A)=\bar A=[\bar a:\bar b:\bar c]\in \mathbb P^2(\mathbb F_p)$ .
(Elementary reference :  [Silverman-Tate, Rational Points on Elliptic Curve](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Rational_Points_on_Elliptic_Curves.html?id=_lzhBwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y), A5, page 302)
Given a subvariety $W\subset \mathbb P^2$ we'll call $\overline W=r_p(W)\subset \mathbb P^2_{\mathbb F_p}$ its image under $r_p$.
Now if $p, l \equiv 3 \operatorname {mod} 4$ are distinct primes we get $$\operatorname {card}[\overline {V_p}(\mathbb F_p)]=1 \quad  (\bullet) \quad\operatorname {but} \quad \operatorname {card}[\overline{V_l}(\mathbb F_p)]=p+1 \quad  (\bullet \bullet)$$ showing that $V_p, V_l\subset \mathbb P^2$ are not isomorphic since  their images $\overline {V_p},\overline {V_l}$ under $r_p$ are not isomorphic in $\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb F_p}$.
The reason that  $\overline {V_p},\overline {V_l}$ are not isomorphic in $\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb F_p}$ is that their $\mathbb F_p$ points are sets $\overline {V_p}(\mathbb F_p),\overline {V_l}(\mathbb F_p)$ of different cardinalities (namely $1$ and $p+1$).
**Supplementary Explanations**
$(\bullet )$ The equality $\operatorname {card}r_p(V_p)=1$ follows from $x^2+y^2=0$ having as solution in $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb F_p)$ only the point $[0:0:1]$.
 $(\bullet \bullet)$ The  equality $\operatorname {card}r_p(V_l)=p+1$ is due to the conic $r_p(V_l)\subset \mathbb P^2(\mathbb F_p)$  being isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb F_p)$, since   it  has  an $\mathbb F_p$-point (recall that in the finite field $\mathbb F_p$ we can solve $x^2+y^2=l\:$ for **any** $ l \in \mathbb F_p^*$) .

**Personal remark**
The numerous comments pertaining to question and answer on this thread (not mentioning all the erased ones) prove that this exercise at the very beginning of Silverman's book is completely out of place.

Comment: But none of those $p+1$ points in $r_p(V_l)$ are actually in the image of $r_p$ (nor is the point $(0,0,1)\in r_p(V_p)$, so I don't see how this proves the result. Again, my understanding of "isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$" is that it means: $V_p(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})\cong V_q(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ via some morphism whose components lie in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: But there is no morphism from $V_l$ (as a variety in $\mathbb{P}^2(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$) to $\overline{V}_l(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Clearly we are talking past each other on something important, but I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Dear rogerl, I find Silverman's treatment of basic algebraic geometry hopelessly messy and I will no longer try to contort myself into his approach.  The scheme-theoretic  point of view is limpid: we have two closed projective subschemes $V_p=V(X^2+Y^2-pZ^2)\subset \mathbb P^2_\mathbb Z , V_l=V(X^2+Y^2-lZ^2)\subset \mathbb P^2_\mathbb Z$. They are not isomorphic and to prove that it suffices to prove that their points $\overline {V_p}(\mathbb F_p),\overline {V_l}(\mathbb F_p)$ over $\mathbb F_p$ are sets of different cardinalities.

Comment: Fair enough; I find it messy myself. But since I don't know schemes, I guess this will have to go unsolved from my point of view. Thanks for your attention and help. And I agree that this exercise is out of place in the book.

Comment: You might want to look at [Milne's great notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ectext5.pdf) on the subject. Milne's expertise shines through, even though there is no explicit mention of   schemes in his course, which is elementary, rigorous and rich in results.

Comment: Funny you should say that...my real goal is to understand elliptic curves and their interaction with modular forms...I know about Milne's book and just yesterday purchased a hard copy version. Good to know I didn't make a mistake. Milne's writing is generally clear and pretty down to earth.

Comment: 1) Dear @GeorgesElencwajg:  I am afraid that I am not entirely convinced... Silverman's question asked that one show that the two varieties are not isomorphic over $ \mathbb Q$. It seems to me that what you have done here is to choose (the obvious, God-given) models over $\mathbb Z$, and then show that these are not isomorphic over $\mathbb Z$.  I don't think this enough. What do you make of the following (with change of notation):  (cont)

Comment: 2) consider the graded rings $S= {\mathbb Z}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2-pz^2)$, and $T={\mathbb Z}[x,y,z]/(px^2+py^2-z^2)$ , with $p\equiv -1 \pmod 4$; write $X = \mathop{\rm Proj} S$ and $Y = \mathop{\rm Proj} T$. The schemes $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic over $\mathbb Z$, as in your answer: $X({\mathbb F}_p)= \left\{(0:0:1) \right\} $, whereas $Y({\mathbb F}_p) = \{ (1: n : 0  ), ( m:1:0) \mid n, m \in {\mathbb F}_p\} $. On the other hand, $X\otimes{\mathbb  Q} \simeq Y\otimes {\mathbb Q} $:  (cont)

Comment: 3) The iso of graded rings $\lambda \colon {\mathbb Q}[x,y,z] \to {\mathbb Q}[x,y,z]$, defined by $\lambda ( x) = x, \lambda (y) =y, \lambda (z) = pz$, carries $T\otimes {\mathbb Q}$ isomorphically to $S\otimes {\mathbb Q}$. Therefore, it seems to me the method is not enough for Silverman's question. Am I misunderstanding this? Comments, objections, corrections?

Comment: Dear @peter a g: you are perfectly right, I have only proved the non-isomorphism over $\mathbb Z$.  I have now edited my answer in order to make that explicit . In a similar vein the quadratic forms $x^2+y^2-pz^2$ over $\mathbb Q$ are non-congruent for different $p$'s (they have different determinants mod. $\mathbb Q^{*2})$ but that also does not suffice to prove non-isomorphism of the corresponding conics. Anyway, I am very grateful for your most illuminating comments and I would be very happy if you posted a solution for the non-isomorphism over $\mathbb Q$ .

Comment: I will try to do so (as sketched in the last set of comments below Roger's original question). However, it involves the p-adics, even if correct, so is probably not what was wanted. On the other hand, regardless of the tools needed, I actually disagree about your comment  that the question is misplaced - as it provokes thought... One can certainly say that number theory has a lot of simple questions with difficult answers. In any case, I am tempted to write Silverman - who is very helpful! -  and ask him to take a look (once I've posted) at this page, and say what he had in mind. OK?

Comment: BTW, there is a nice (a.k.a. entertaining) presentation by Pierre Cartier - en anglais! in English - on the birth of the notions of spectrum and scheme: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etdvnswIhMw and on the people in the room at the time...

Comment: Dear @peter a g, 1)  we'll agree to disagree on the aim of exercises: I have always given my students  exercises  which they could solve from what I told them in my course. I could then give more ambitious students harder stuff for thought without discouraging the others. 2) Thanks for the link. I have heard many talks by the pleasantly  talkative Cartier and by Serre on the genesis of scheme theory. At the inauguration of our new department in Nice, Serre rebuked Deligne for failing to properly acknowledge the contribution of Grothendieck's predecessors in the genesis of scheme theory. :-)

Comment: 3) And, yes, by all means do write  Silverman and ask him what he had in mind.

Comment: You might be right about how discouraging things can be... I know I was often discouraged!  Now, I am mostly only resigned.

Comment: @peterag I *did* write Silverman, a few days back, and he replied that he had in mind the $p$-adic proof (and agreed that the exercise was hard for that point in the book): $V_p(\mathbb{Q}_q)$ is nonempty since there is a solution in $\mathbb{F}_q$ which lifts, while $V_p(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is empty. Finally, any $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphism is also a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-isomorphism.

Comment: @rogerl - do you want to post the solution, officially? Or would you like me to do it? As it is, it is less useful to have it buried in the 10,000 comments...

Comment: @peterag Either you or George, whomever seems more responsible for it, should post it. If you guys don't want to, I'm happy to do so.